# Speed up pixel format conversion - BGR packed to RGB planar

Tags: c#, arrays, image-processing, intrinsics, pixelformat

From a SDK I get images that have the pixel format BGR packed, i.e. `BGRBGRBGR`. For another application, I need to convert this format to RGB planar `RRRGGGBBB`. I don't want to use an extra library just for this task, so I have to use my own code to convert between the formats.

I am using C# .NET 4.5 32bit and the data is in byte arrays which have the same size.

Right now I am iterating through the array source and assigning the BGR values to their appropriate places in the target array, but that takes too long (250ms for a 1.3 megapixel image). The processor the code runs at is a Intel Atom E680 and has access to MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3.

Unfortunately I don't have knowledge of intrinsics and couldn't convert code for a similar problem like [Fast method to copy memory with translation - ARGB to BGR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804101/fast-method-to-copy-memory-with-translation-argb-to-bgr) to suit my needs.

The code I am currently using to convert between the pixel formats is:

```
// the array with the BGRBGRBGR pixel data
byte[] source;
// the array with the RRRGGGBBB pixel data
byte[] result;
// the amount of pixels in one channel, width*height
int imageSize;

for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i += 3)
{
    result[i/3] = source[i + 2]; // R
    result[i/3 + imageSize] = source[i + 1]; // G
    result[i/3 + imageSize * 2] = source[i]; // B
}
```

I tried splitting the access to the source array into three loops, one for each channel, but it didn't really help. So I'm open to suggestions.

```
for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i += 3)
{
    result[i/3] = source[i + 2]; // R
}

for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i += 3)
{
    result[i/3 + imageSize] = source[i + 1]; // G
}

for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i += 3)
{
    result[i/3 + imageSize * 2] = source[i]; // B
}
```

edit: I got it down to 180ms by removing the division and multiplication like this, but is there a way to make it even faster? It still is very slow which I guess is because the memory reads/writes aren't very optimal.

```
int targetPosition = 0;
int imageSize2 = imageSize * 2;
for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i += 3)
{
    result[targetPosition] = source[i + 2]; // R
    targetPosition++;
}

targetPosition = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i += 3)
{
    result[targetPosition + imageSize] = source[i + 1]; // G
    targetPosition++;
}

targetPosition = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i += 3)
{
    result[targetPosition + imageSize2] = source[i]; // B
    targetPosition++;
}
```

Thanks to MBo's answer, I was able to reduce the time from 180ms to 90ms! Here is the code:

Converter.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

BOOL __stdcall DllMain(HINSTANCE hInst, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved) {
return  TRUE;
}

const unsigned char Mask[] = { 0, 3, 6, 9, 
                           1, 4, 7, 10, 
                           2, 5, 8, 11, 
                           12, 13, 14, 15};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) char* __stdcall ConvertPixelFormat(unsigned char* source, unsigned char *target, int imgSize) {

_asm {
    //interleave r1g1b1 r2g2b2 r3g3b3 r4b4g4 r5b5g5 r6... to planar
    //           r1r2r3r4r5..... g1g2g3g4g5... b1b2b3b4b5...
        push edi
        push esi
        mov eax, source      //A address
        mov edx, target      //B address
        mov ecx, imgSize
        movdqu xmm5, Mask    //load shuffling mask
        mov edi, imgSize     //load interleave step
        mov esi, eax
        add esi, edi
        add esi, edi
        add esi, edi
        shr ecx, 2           //divide count by 4
        dec ecx              //exclude last array chunk
        jle Rest

    Cycle:
        movdqu xmm0, [eax]        //load 16 bytes
        pshufb xmm0, xmm5         //shuffle bytes, we are interested in 12 ones
        movd [edx], xmm0          //store 4 bytes of R
        psrldq xmm0, 4            //shift right register, now G is on the end
        movd [edx + edi], xmm0    //store 4 bytes of G to proper place
        psrldq xmm0, 4            //do the same for B
        movd [edx + 2 * edi], xmm0
        add eax, 12               //shift source index to the next portion
        add edx, 4                //shift destination index
        loop Cycle

    Rest:                       //treat the rest of array
        cmp eax, esi
        jae Finish
        mov ecx, [eax]
        mov [edx], cl           //R
        mov [edx + edi], ch     //G
        shr ecx, 16
        mov [edx + 2 * edi], cl //B
        add eax, 3
        add edx, 1
        jmp Rest

    Finish:
        pop esi
        pop edi
    }
}
```

C# file:

```
// Code to define the method
[DllImport("Converter.dll")]
unsafe static extern void ConvertPixelFormat(byte* source, byte* target, int imgSize);

// Code to execute the conversion
unsafe
{
    fixed (byte* sourcePointer = &source[0])
    {
        fixed (byte* resultPointer = &result[0])
        {
            ConvertPixelFormat(sourcePointer, resultPointer, imageSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just test multiple ways, print the time and choose the fastest. I suggest to remove divisions and multiplications from inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to make it faster but wonder if there is still a way to improve it.

Comment: I think you are reaching the speed limit of your approach. You can improve it by changing approach - e.g. using multiple processors (threads).

Comment: Do you need it to be safe? Is unsafe code (with pointers) ok?

Comment: Doesn't need to be safe. But I already got a great answer with pointers and asm code which satisfies me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented this interleaving problem in Delphi and examined built-in asm. I have not intrinsics, so used plain assembler.
 `pshufb` is equal to `_mm_shuffle_epi8` ([SSSE3 intrinsic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531427.aspx))

At every cycle step I load 16 bytes `(r1g1b1 r2g2b2 r3g3b3 r4b4g4 r5b5g5 r6)` to 128-bit XMM register, shuffle them into `(r1r2r3r4 g1g2g3g4 b1b2b3b4 xxxx)` order, and save r,g,b chunks to destination memory (ignoring last 4 bytes). Next step loads `(r5b5g5 r6g6b6 r7g7b7 ...)` and so on.

**Note** that for code simplification I did not treat the very tail of array properly in the first code version. Since you are able to use this code, I've made needed corrections.

*First version issue example:

imgSize = 32

array size = 96 bytes

32/4 = 8 cycles

the last cycle starts from 84th byte and read 16 bytes upto 99th byte - so we run out of array range!

I just added guard bytes here: `GetMem(A, Size * 3 + 15);`, but for real task it could be unapplicable, so it is worth to have special treatment of the last array chunk.*

This code takes 967 ms for pascal variant and 140 ms for asm variant to convert two hundred 1.3MP cadrs on i5-4670 machine (processor itself is 6-8x faster for single thread than Atom 680). Speed is about 0.75 GB/Sec (pas) and 5.4 GB/Sec (asm)

```
const
  Mask: array[0..15] of Byte = ( 0, 3, 6, 9,
                                 1, 4, 7, 10,
                                 2, 5, 8, 11,
                                 12, 13, 14, 15);
var
  A, B: PByteArray;
  i, N, Size: Integer;
  t1, t2: DWord;
begin
  Size := 1280 * 960 * 200;
  GetMem(A, Size * 3);
  GetMem(B, Size * 3);

  for i := 0 to Size - 1 do begin
    A[3 * i] := 1;
    A[3 * i + 1] := 2;
    A[3 * i + 2] := 3;
  end;

  t1 := GetTickCount;
  for i := 0 to Size - 1 do begin
    B[i] := A[3 * i];
    B[i + Size] := A[3 * i + 1];
    B[i + 2 * Size] := A[3 * i + 2];
  end;
  t2:= GetTickCount;

    //interleave r1g1b1 r2g2b2 r3g3b3 r4b4g4 r5b5g5 r6... to planar
    //r1r2r3r4r5..... g1g2g3g4g5... b1b2b3b4b5...
  asm
    push edi
    push esi
    mov eax, A      //A address
    mov edx, B      //B address
    mov ecx, Size
    movdqu xmm5, Mask   //load shuffling mask
    mov edi, Size       //load interleave step
    mov esi, eax
    add esi, edi
    add esi, edi
    add esi, edi
    shr ecx, 2      //divide count by 4
    dec ecx         //exclude last array chunk
    jle @@Rest

  @@Cycle:
    movdqu xmm0, [eax]   //load 16 bytes
    pshufb xmm0, xmm5    //shuffle bytes, we are interested in 12 ones
    movd [edx], xmm0     //store 4 bytes of R
    psrldq xmm0, 4        //shift right register, now G is on the end
    movd [edx + edi], xmm0   //store 4 bytes of G to proper place
    psrldq xmm0, 4            //do the same for B
    movd [edx + 2 * edi], xmm0
    add eax, 12               //shift source index to the next portion
    add edx, 4                //shift destination index
    loop @@Cycle

   @@Rest:       //treat the rest of array
    cmp eax, esi
    jae @@Finish
    mov ecx, [eax]
    mov [edx], cl   //R
    mov [edx + edi], ch  //G
    shr ecx, 16
    mov [edx + 2 * edi], cl //B
    add eax, 3
    add edx, 1
    jmp @@Rest
  @@Finish:

    pop esi
    pop edi
  end;

  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('pas %d asm %d', [t2-t1, GetTickCount - t2]));
  FreeMem(A);
  FreeMem(B);
```

Comment: Very helpful! It reduced the needed time by a factor of 2. Thank you.

Comment: Since my image width needs to be divisible by 8, I don't need to worry about the tail of array because the step size of 4 means that it will always process the whole array, right?

Comment: No, I've added explanation and made corrections to avoid potential problems (access violation). See corrected code (both before and after the main cycle)

Answer (score 0):

You may try counting backwards, i.e. `int i = source.Length - 1; i >=0 ; i -= 3`, so the property `source.Length` is read only once per for loop, not at every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice of Ivan and came up with this improvement which gets rid of the division (implemented in C):

```c
    int offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(source); i += 3) {
        offset++;
        result[offset] = source[i + 2];  // R
        result[offset + imageSize] = source[i + 1];  // G
        result[offset + imageSize * 2] = source[i];  // B
    }
```

this saves about 40% runtime on my machine.

Comment: Thanks, but I was faster, see edit :) It improved quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

First step: avoid reading source multiple times (see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27542680/949044 ). This also plays nice with CPU cache, which is currently underused: you're reading 1 byte out of 3, so a 2/3ds of a cache line is thrown out.
So it could go like this:

```
int targetPositionR = 0;
int targetPositionG = imageSize;
int targetPositionB = imageSize * 2;
for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i += 3)
{
    result[targetPositionB] = source[i]; // B
    result[targetPositionG] = source[i + 1]; // G
    result[targetPositionR] = source[i + 2]; // R
    targetPositionB++;
    targetPositionG++;
    targetPositionR++;
}
```

Second step: writes 4 bytes at a time, rather than 1 byte. However, it requires an additional buffer and a copy:

```
int[] dwPlanar = new int[imageSize*3/4];
int targetPositionR = 0;
int targetPositionG = imageSize / 4;
int targetPositionB = imageSize * 2 / 4;
for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i += 12)
{
    int dwB = (source[i  ]) | (source[i+3] << 8) | (source[i+6] << 16) | (source[i+9]  << 24);
    int dwG = (source[i+1]) | (source[i+4] << 8) | (source[i+7] << 16) | (source[i+10] << 24);
    int dwR = (source[i+2]) | (source[i+5] << 8) | (source[i+8] << 16) | (source[i+11] << 24);
    dwPlanar[targetPositionB] = dwB; // B
    dwPlanar[targetPositionG] = dwG; // G
    dwPlanar[targetPositionR] = dwR; // R
    targetPositionB++;
    targetPositionG++;
    targetPositionR++;
}
Buffer.BlockCopy(dwPlanar,0,result,0,imageSize * 3);
```

I suppose it will help, because c# will make less array bounds checks, and it is in general a better idea to write in larger chunks whenever possible.

(Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with c# and I do not know if this code will even compile, it is only an algorithm).